vim - Unmap predefined command, specifically X
Fairly simple, I never want to encrypt a file using vim (and if I did, I could temporarily reinstate this) so I would like to remove :X as a possible action, when attempting to type :x (which requires a shift key on my keyboard for the first but not second key). Either remapping this to replicate :x, or just do nothing, i.e. command not found or something.
The unmap command doesn't work, its not a mapping, and I can't use command X x to do want I want either as X is a reserved name.

:X is not a mapping so there is no point in trying to "unmap" it.
Generally speaking, the few mappings you can find in vanilla Vim come from a) plugins distributed with Vim (Netrw, etc.) and b) the scripts providing menus for the GUI. Other than that, stuff like :X, normal mode w, etc. are not "mappings" so they can't be "unmapped". If you want to get rid of a built-in normal/insert/visual/etc. mode command, you must map it to <nop>:
nmap w <nop>

You can also use mappings to switch the meaning of built-in commands:
nnoremap W w
nnoremap w W

Overriding built-in Ex commands is harder. It is not possible to create Ex commands that start with a lowercase character and, as you noticed, there are capitalized commands that are reserved.
But you can do either of two things.
Normal mode mapping
Since :x and :X are both typed from normal mode, you can create a normal mode mapping that does :x when you do :X:
nnoremap :X :x

Command-line mode mapping
Or you can create a command-line mode mapping:
cnoremap X x

The problem, then, is that Vim is going to expand X to x anywhere in the command-line, which can be troublesome if you want to use X in a filename, for example. This is easily fixable by checking the position of the cursor:
cnoremap <expr> X getcmdpos() == 1 ? 'x' : 'X'

Reference:
:help mapmode-c
:help :map-<expr>
:help getcmdpos()
:help ternary


Nice touch showing two ways of doing the impossible.

Great two suggests, both of which I assume wouldn't work. Using a normal mode remapping of :X is a little bit more messy as now any time you start writing a : command, it waits before typing. So the second (with the filename fix) is perfect. Thanks!

There is no wait after :, in practice.
